# Changing sorting on Nginx autoindex

Tags: nginx

I am using `autoindex` with nginx for a specific endpoint that lists a bunch of folders. Is it possible to change the sorting direction from alphabetical to by modified date?

Comment: https://github.com/aperezdc/ngx-fancyindex

Answer (score 2):

Not without rewriting the module.
You can use a PHP script to display whatever you like, or run a task which creates a html page.
Or even use Lua to create this for you and check if something has changed, then either display from cache or re-generate.